# Setting the table view cell's name based on picker selection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have made a table view with a button that adds cells. I am new to this area of objective C so I have some questions. I also have it so the cell can be tapped and a detailViewController is opened. The detailViewController has a picker in it. How could I set the pickers selection to be the title of the tableViewCell? Their is going to be more than 1 table view cell, that will have to have different titles based on the pickers selection so do I need to make different views for each cell? Sorry if these questions are stupid, i'm just really new to this area.

---

### Edit

I have been doing my homework and came up with some code, but I am still getting an error. I have two views, one is a tableViewController, and one is the one with the picker. I have declared the cell and set its identifier to cell. I then imported the .h file from my tableViewController to my pickerViewController. But when I set the title, i get an error. The code for setting my title is

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    int select = row;
    if (select == 0) {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Title";
    } else
```

}
But I am getting the error "Use of undeclared identifier cell".

In the .h file of the tableViewController has this `UITableViewCell *cell;` in it

And the .m file has this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDate *object = _objects[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [object description];
    return cell;
}
```

Also in the .m file of the pickerViewController I have this `#import "TableViewController.h"

Am I doing something wrong? should I be getting this error? Sorry if this is hard to understand, because I had trouble turning my problem into words.

Comment: You need to set the identifier of the prototype cell (in storyboard) to "cell" in the attributes inspector for the reuse identifier to work. That will handle the error you are getting now, but won't fix your problem.

Comment: the error is still there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is not correct. You basically need  the following steps.

1) Your array or dictionary that you use to populate the table view needs to have a property (or key if it's a dictionary) for "title". You would use that to set the title in each cell. It can be an empty string initially, if you don't set any titles until the user picks something from the picker

2) When you open the detail view controller, you should keep a reference to the selected row in a property (in the table view controller). If you're doing the transition in code, this would be in tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:, if you're using segues it should be done in prepareForSegue:. The controller should also set itself as the delegate of the detail controller in one of these two methods.

3) The detail controller should have a delegate protocol with one method that passes the title back to the table view controller. After the user makes a selection in the picker, call the delegate method. The table view controller would implement this method and use the row information stored in its property to add that title string to the array, and then  update the table view.

Comment: Im pretty new to this, so i dont quite follow you. So I need some help. How would I set its property?

Comment: @user2660874,  Which step are you asking about?

Comment: In the first step you says "Your array or dictionary that you use to populate the table view needs to have a property". And I do t know how to set a property

Answer (score 0):

When your cell is tapped, you are using the

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
       didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method to show your UIPickerView, right? You will need to access this selected row/cell whenever your pickerViewDidSelectRow function is called, in order to change the cell's title. There are a bunch of ways you can do this.

The way that is closest to the way you have been trying to implement is to save a pointer to the selected cell in the tableViewDidSelectRowAtIndexPath method with:

```
self.selectedCell = [tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

For this to work, you will need to change the name of your 'cell' in .h file to 'selectedCell'. I suggest this change as 'cell' can be confusing.

Then, in your pickerViewDidSelectRowInComponent, you will set the title of your selected cell like this:

```
self.selectedCell.textLabel.text = @"Title";
```

Comment: can I set it from a different view cintroller?